# Is it possible to build dynamic custom object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-visualization, javascript-objects

I am working on a website that has Google charts, the website includes JavaScript Ajax that pulls data from web service and supposed to create object that will be passed to chart.

If it possible to build this custom object, would you mind giving me an example of how to do so, my problem is in understanding how exactly I construct it from custom values (lets say array).

The object looks like

```
 chart_data.addRows([
        ['1', 1000, 400, 200],
        ['2', 1000, 460, 200],
        ['3', 860, 580, 200],
        ['4', 1030, 540, null],
        ['5', null, 540, null]
  ]);
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call is using an array (of arrays), not an object. You could build the array for example like this, and call the function using the variable:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(['1', 1000, 400, 200]);
arr.push(['2', 1000, 460, 200]);
arr.push(['3', 860, 580, 200]);
arr.push(['4', 1030, 540, null]);
arr.push(['5', null, 540, null]);

chart_data.addRows(arr);
```

Each of the arrays in the array could also be build dynamically:

```
var arr1 = [];
arr1.push('1');
arr1.push(1000);
arr1.push(400);
arr1.push(200);
arr.push(arr1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example I am going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can build dynamic object like this

```
var ob = new Object();
ob.property1 = 'value1';
ob.property2 = 'value2';
```

And let's say you don't know the name of properties at run time , you can try this also

```
var ob = new Object();
for(var i = 0; i< 3; i++) ob['property'+i] = value[i];
```

and access them like ob.property1 or ob.property2

Comment: Unfortunately properties not known to me.

Comment: what exactly you want in new dynamic object.. you want new methods for the object ? that is also allowed..